# MVC Binding a collection of sub types to post model

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, inheritance, model, model-binding

My problem:
To get the current subtype of the Question i can't just call GetValue("ModelType") since Questions is a collection. So how do i get the subtype for the current Question in the collection in the custom Model Binder? So this won't work:

```
var typeValue = bindingContext.ValueProvider.GetValue("ModelType");
```

Here is a somewhat simplified version of my code.. I have a following model:

```cs
public class PostViewModel
{
    public string Title { get; set; }
    public List<Question> Questions { get; set; }
}

public class Question
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
}

public class SingleChoice : Question
{
    public List<Answers> AnswerOptions { get; set; }
}
public class TextQuestion : Question
{
    public string Value { get; set; }
}
```

Then i have created the following model binder:

```cs
public class QuestionModelBinder : DefaultModelBinder
{
    protected override object CreateModel(ControllerContext controllerContext, ModelBindingContext bindingContext, Type modelType)
    {
        if (modelType.Equals(typeof(Question)))
        {

            var typeValue = bindingContext.ValueProvider.GetValue("ModelType");
            var type = Type.GetType(
                (string)typeValue.ConvertTo(typeof(string)),
                true
            );
            if (!typeof(Question).IsAssignableFrom(type))
            {
                throw new InvalidOperationException("Bad Type");
            }


            var obj = Activator.CreateInstance(type);                
            bindingContext.ModelMetadata = ModelMetadataProviders.Current.GetMetadataForType(() => obj, type);
            bindingContext.ModelMetadata.Model = obj;
            return obj;
        }

        return base.CreateModel(controllerContext, bindingContext, modelType);
    }
}
```

And my view looks like this:

//View A

```
@model PostModel

@Html.EditorFor(m => m.Questions)
```

//View B

```
@model QuestionViewModel
<div>
@Html.HiddenFor(m => m.Id)
@Html.Hidden("ModelType", Model.GetType())
@switch (Model.QuestionType)
{
    case QuestionType.OpenText:
        @Html.Partial("EditorTemplates/Types/TextViewModel", Model)
        break;
    case QuestionType.SingleChoice:
    @Html.Partial("EditorTemplates/Types/SingleChoiceViewModel", Model)
        break;

}
</div>
```

Comment: `@Html.Hidden("ModelType", Model.Questions.FirstOrDefault().GetType())` ?

Comment: Thnx, but the value in the hidden field is not the problem..